# Django display related objects inside related objects in the admin

Tags: django, model, admin

According to my assignment admin must be able to create Polls with Questions (create, delete, update) and Choices related to this questions. All of this should be displayed and changable on the same admin page.

```
Poll
|
|_question_1
|    |
|    |_choice_1(text)
|    |
|    |_choice_2
|    |
|    |_choice_3
|
|_question_2
|    |
|    |_choice_1
|    |
|    |_choice_2
|    |
|    |_choice_3
|
|_question_3
     |
     |_choice_1
     |
     |_choice_2
     |
     |_choice_3
```

Ok, it's not a problem to display one level of nesting like so on

```
class QuestionInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Question


class PollAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        QuestionInline,
    ]
```

But how to do to get the required poll design structure?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this library](https://django-nested-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) it should provide the functionality.